# Client vpn can't see local subnet of other vpn client

Tags: openvpn

This is the current network i have. From client pc, i want to reach the client subnet

[image: Current network]

My Server Openvpn is part of my Asus router RT-AC86U with a merlin firmware
[image]

then in /jffs/configs/openvpn/ccd i have a file for the client pikb400

```
iroute 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

my clients have the following :

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote XXXXXXX 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
float
ncp-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:AES-256-CBC:AES-128-CBC
keepalive 15 60
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/auth.txt
remote-cert-tls server
```

From client pc, when i check the route taken to 192.168.1.254 i get this

```
$ tracert 192.168.1.254

Tracing route to 192.168.1.254 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    46 ms    47 ms    49 ms  10.8.0.3
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

It's almost as if it is stuck on my pikb400 client ? . None of the vpn client have a firewall and i ran `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` on pikb400 client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI i found the solution to my issues. I need to add some iptable rules to forward traffic from the tun interface to my subnet interface.
See details https://arashmilani.com/post?id=53